# Kendo-knockout grid doesn't filter date column

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo-knockout framework. I am having a problem with filtering a date column in the grid. Filtering a date always returns 0 results. I noticed that a traditional kendo grid will have filter options being: Is equal to, Is not equal to, Is after or equal to, Is after, Is before or equal to, Is before. However, my kendo-knockout grid uses the following filter options for the date column: Is equal to, Is not equal to, Starts with, Contains, Does not contain, Ends with.

It would seem like kendo is thinking that the date column is a string column, which is why the filter options are the same for both a string column and a date column in my grid.

Below is my code. Notice in failedTradeModel that I subscribe to each field in order to have sorting and filtering work. This had solved a previous problem where the kendo-knockout grid wouldn't sort or filter at all without doing this subscription (I had seen this as a solution here: [Kendo UI and knockout.js rowTemplate sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700510/kendo-ui-and-knockout-js-rowtemplate-sorting)).

The price column sorts and filters fine, it's just the TradeDate column that is having the problem mentioned above.

Any help?

EDIT: for anyone interested, I have posted an answer for a working solution below. The trick was to add 'type: "data"' for the date column in failesGridConfig object. I also had to set self.TradeDateSort to a date object in failedTradeModel function.

```
var ViewModel = function () {
var self = this;  
self.failedTradesAry = ko.observableArray();

self.initializePage = function () {
    $.getJSON(initalizeFailedTradesPageUrl, null, function (data) {
        dataReturned = data.FailedTrades;

        self.failedTradesAry(ko.utils.arrayMap(dataReturned, function (item) {
            var g = new failedTradeModel(self);
            ko.mapping.fromJS(item, {}, g);
            return g;
        }));
    });
};


self.failesGridConfig = {
    data: self.failedTradesAry,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    rowTemplate: 'rowTmpl',
    useKOTemplates: true,
    columns: [
        { 
            field: 'TradeDateSort', 
            title: 'Trade Date', 
            width: 100,
            filterable: {
                ui: "datepicker"
            }
        },
        { 
            field: 'PriceSort', 
            title: 'Price', 
            width: 100 
        }
      ]
    };
};

var failedTradeModel = function (parentVm, data) {
    var self = this;

    self.TradeDateSort;
    self.TradeDate = ko.observable();
    self.TradeDate.subscribe(function (value) {
        self.TradeDateSort = value;
    });

    self.PriceSort;
    self.Price = ko.observable();
    self.Price.subscribe(function (value) {
        self.PriceSort = value;
    });

    return self;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ViewModel = function () {
var self = this;  
self.failedTradesAry = ko.observableArray();

self.initializePage = function () {
    $.getJSON(initalizeFailedTradesPageUrl, null, function (data) {
        dataReturned = data.FailedTrades;

        self.failedTradesAry(ko.utils.arrayMap(dataReturned, function (item) {
            var g = new failedTradeModel(self);
            ko.mapping.fromJS(item, {}, g);
            return g;
        }));
    });
};


self.failesGridConfig = {
    data: self.failedTradesAry,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    rowTemplate: 'rowTmpl',
    useKOTemplates: true,
    columns: [
        { 
            field: 'TradeDateSort', 
            title: 'Trade Date', 
            width: 100,
            filterable: {
                ui: "datepicker"
            },
            type: "date" 
        },
        { 
            field: 'PriceSort', 
            title: 'Price', 
            width: 100 
        }
      ]
};
};

var failedTradeModel = function (parentVm, data) {
var self = this;

self.TradeDateSort;
self.TradeDate = ko.observable();
self.TradeDate.subscribe(function (value) {
    var dt = new Date(value);
    self.TradeDateSort = dt;
});

self.PriceSort;
self.Price = ko.observable();
self.Price.subscribe(function (value) {
    self.PriceSort = value;
});

return self;
};
```